# How to extract full entities from a bunch of text (not partial entities)

Tags: nlp

This is probably a classical NLP problem, but how do I extract the FULL entity in a bunch of tweets?

For instance, suppose there's a bunch of tweets that mention "Boston" and "marathon", both in the same tweet. How do I know I should I extract "Boston marathon" and not just Boston or marathon?

Similarly, suppose there's a lot of tweets that mention "Game of Thrones". How would I know the entity to be extracted is Game of Thrones, not just Game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing to try may be extracting collocations. See [the following article](http://tdunning.blogspot.com/2008/03/surprise-and-coincidence.html) for an introduction to this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Most named entity recogniser use the so-called IOB (inside-outside-beginning) tagging scheme exactly because of the scenario you are asking about. For instance, the sentence

```
John saw Game of Thrones.
```

should be tagged as

```
John/B-PERSON saw/O Game/B-MISC of/I-MISC Thrones/I-MISC.
```

Notice how the second and third tokens of "Game of thrones" are tagged as being inside a named entity, which begins at "Game". Of course, there is no guarantee that the tagger you are using will produce this exact sequence of tags.

You can read more about IOB in the [NLTK book](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with DBpedia-Spotlight endpoint..

http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/spot/?text=

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently extracting named entities from a event databse. I've tried several libraries NLTK, PHP scripts etc. But the best one I find is Stanford NER: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/.

english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz

```
<PERSON>John</PERSON> saw Game of Thrones.
```

english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz

```
John saw <ORGANIZATION>Game of Thrones</ORGANIZATION>.
```

Just ignore the classified type.

I use different classifiers to extract the entities from the text. After that I use the Stanford Parser: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/

Typed dependencies, collapsed

```
nsubj(saw-2, John-1)
root(ROOT-0, saw-2)
dobj(saw-2, Game-3)
prep_of(Game-3, Thrones-5)
```

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf

to specify which named entities I want or not.